# excel macro to change values in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file coming every month which has few columns with more than 50K rows. I usually need to replace values in column B with different values such as if any field in column B contains ASD , replace it with XYZ. And there is a list of value that needs to be replaced. Also as mentioned above old value can be more than once in column B and needs to be replaced .

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code yet ??

Answer (score 2):

Record a macro [View > Macros > Record Macro]

Do the find+replace operation

Stop recording.

Now view Macros > Edit.

You will see the newly recorded Macro which does the find+replace, and you can edit this to your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
Sub test()
'this will get you the last row number in column "B"
lastRow = Sheets("SheetName").Cells(Sheets("SheetName").Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Row

'loop through all cells in coulmn "B" and replace text as needed
For i = 1 To lastRow
    'you can add multiple lines for each values that needs to be replaced
    Sheets("SheetName").Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(Sheets("SheetName").Cells(i, 2).Value, "ABC", "XYX")
Next i

End Sub
```

Where 'SheetName' is your sheet's name. Hope that is what you are looking for!